# Running SU commands in non-rooted device

Tags: android, linux, root, su, userid

I have a non-rooted device, in which I want to run commands from my application.
My application is a system application (got the needed key for that) - but the built-in `su` of the device does not allow uid 1000 (of the system app) to run `su` commands.
What I've done is changing the following file: [su.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/android-5.0.2_r1/su/su.c) by removing the: `if (myuid != AID_ROOT && myuid != AID_SHELL) {` part. I compiled it using ndk tools, put it inside my `/system/xbin/` folder under the name `mysu`.

I then entered `adb` and remounted the system for `rw`, `chmoded 777` the file (all using the original `su`), and remounted it back.

The problem - this doesn't work. Any commands I'm trying to run (even from the shell) using `mysu`, that require special permissions (like deleting from specific folders) don't work, as I'm getting "Permission denied". For example:
`rm failed for com_rti_tsk.bin, Permission denied`.

Is there a solution? I don't believe that "overwriting" the original `su` with `mysu` will solve it (it's only a name) - but will it help? (I don't want to reformat the device again). What options do I have?

The bottom line is that I need to delete certain files (that require elevated permissions), I can run as system app, what options do I have?

Comment: No, you **do not** need to do that.  If you are making a custom build (apparently the case as you have a root adb), you can do things *properly by design* rather than improperly by *abusing* a root shim at runtime (especially if you are going to leave the door wide open for everyone, as your change would if it worked).  As for your problem, it's possible that you've made the classic "su is not sticky in the parent process" mistake, but that wouldn't matter as you would ultimately run into the enforcing selinux in modern releases.

Comment: **If you must use root, at least use the best of existing methods** rather than inventing something yourself.  They have a workaround for the selinux issue, and, controversial as that may be, better to ride on their efforts and the lessons of their mistakes than try to implement this yourself.

Comment: Well, using the Android way of deleting files give me "permission denied" no matter if I try using `File.delete()` or `File.rename()`.
The application is made for inner usage and will not go out, so there is no fear of abusing the security breach.
I did not understand your last comment

Comment: You shouldn't be changing the system partition from Android application code, **period**.  If you are building a custom Android installation, do that from carefully vetted native code that runs under linux before the Android stack starts up, ideally code running in the recovery image.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, can you point me to such existing methods, cause I've been searching unsuccesfully so far

Comment: Study how the OTA installer on the recovery partition works (ie, update.zip and all that)

Comment: By the way it's complicated but i'm not making a custom build. I'm building an application above it. I have the key to sign it, but other than that I have no access to other things I might need that lay underneath

Comment: Then you shouldn't be doing this.  It's not a task for application code.  And your problem statement is also inconsistent - if all you had was the system certificate (which no one should have ever given you!), then you wouldn't be able to change the su executable on the deployed device to persue this idea anyway.  Either solve this the right way, consistent with the way the Android authors do things with /system remaining immutable at runtime, drop the ill-conceived project - or if you must use hackish methods, *at least* review the source code of the latest efforts from the rooting community.